# Why doesnt my timer countdown to 0 in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, timer, nstimer

I have this timer and it starts at 3 and it should countdown to 0 but it stops at 2. I don't get why it doesn't go all they way down to 0. Can you please let me know what Im doing wrong with my code. Thank you!

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var timerToStartGame = 3
var timerCountDownLabel: SKLabelNode! = SKLabelNode()


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

timerCountDownLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "TimeBurner")
timerCountDownLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
timerCountDownLabel.zPosition = 40
timerCountDownLabel.fontSize = 60
timerCountDownLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.4, self.size.height / 1.5)
self.addChild(timerCountDownLabel)



var clock = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("countdown"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}


func countdown() {
    timerCountDownLabel.text = String(timerToStartGame--)
    if timerToStartGame == 0 {
        doAction()
    }

    }


}
```

Comment: Its still stops at 2.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vco07v6znrobkt2/timerTestSK.zip?dl=0

Comment: okay it works but when it hits 2 the func gets called. I need it to be called when the timer hits 0.

Comment: No way to get called when hits two with that condition == 0

Comment: My bad it gets called when it gets to 1.

Comment: Thats because you decrease it after displaying using -- after the var. Move it to the front and start from 4

Comment: I already edited my comment but thats not the point try `String(--timerToStartGame)` and start from 4

Comment: Okay it works, thank you! Do you want to add that as your answer so I could give you the checkmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you decrease it after displaying using -- after the var. Move it to the front and start from 4.

```
timerCountDownLabel.text = String(--timerToStartGame)
```